# how to stop numpy hstack from changing pixel values in opencv

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, image-processing

I'm trying to get an image to display in python using opencv, with a side pane on it. When I use `np.hstack` the main picture becomes unrecognizably white with only a small amount of color. Here's my code:

```
    img = cv2.imread(filename)
    img_with_gt, gt_pane = Evaluator.return_annotated(img, annotations)
    both = np.hstack((img_with_gt, gt_pane))

    cv2.imshow("moo", both)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

And here is the resulting picture

[image: corrupted hstack image]

But If I view `img_with_gt` it looks correct.

[image: groundtruth correct]

Even works with `gt_pane`

[image: gt pane correct]

I can't seem to figure out why this is happening.

Comment: What are the data types of both images?  Specifically, what happens when you do `img_with_gt.dtype` and `gt_pane.dtype` in the REPL? Are they both the same class?

Comment: `gt_pane` is float64, `img_with_gt` is uint8..I changed the construction with the optional `dtype` in my call to `np.zeroes` and it worked perfectly. Thanks!! If you answer it I can give you the check mark.

Comment: There we go.  It was a conflict in data type.  Yup, let me write an answer now :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way I can see that happening is if the data types between the two images don't agree.  Make sure that inside your `return_annotated` method, both `img_with_gt` and `gt_pane` both share the same data type.

You mentioned the fact that you're allocating space for the `gt_pane` to be `float64`.  This represents intensities / colours within the span of `[0-1]`.  Convert the image to `uint8` and multiply the result by 255 to ensure compatibility between the two images.  If you want to leave the image untouched and work on the classification image (the right one), convert to `float64` then divide by 255.

However, if you want to leave the method untouched, a simple fix could can be:

```
both = np.hstack(((255*img_with_gt).astype(np.uint8), gt_pane))
```

You can also go the other way around:

```
both = np.hstack((img_with_gt, gt_pane.astype(np.float64)/255.0))
```